# How to automatically restart a process after a crash or reboot in FreeBsd 11?

Tags: freebsd, systemd

What's the idiomatic way? I'd prefer the most standard and yet simple way with fewer additional dependencies.  Something like an alternative to systemd of Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Installed processes can be restarted automatically by adding to `/etc/rc.conf`

```
yourprocess_enable="YES"
```

[FreeBSD System Startup for Linux Users](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-users/startup.html)

but that's assuming there is a start up script in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/`

[The FreeBSD Handbook - Starting Services](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-starting-services.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not already have an rc.d script for your process, you can fairly easily achieve the desired result with the [daemon(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.0-RELEASE) command. The command will run a child process in the background, and with the command line option `-r`, you can get it to restart the child process if it dies:

```
$ daemon -r /some/path/to/command
```

In later versions of FreeBSD, you can specify `-R <delay in seconds>` to specify how long to wait before restarting the process.

To start the process after rebooting, specify the command in the [crontab(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE) file like this:

```
@reboot daemon -r /some/path/to/command
```

To edit the crontab file, use

```
$ crontab -e
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `<service>_enable=YES` in `/etc/rc.conf` (or relevant `rc.conf.d` files) will start a service on boot.

For restarting on crashes, the canonical way to do it would involve [daemontools](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/daemontools/).

Answer (score -1):

You can add script to cron every (in example) two minutes:

```
#!/bin/sh

process = 'my-secret-service' # process name

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process
then
    echo "$process is alive."
else
    echo "$process is dead, but will be launched."
/usr/local/bin/my-secret-service #launch command

fi
```